# useState-value doesn't change in function when updated (react native)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have the following (simplified) react native code. Please read below the code for the explanation.

```
const [id, setId] = useState(null);

const functionOne = (id) => {
    setId(id);
};

const functionTwo = (newId) => {
    if (id === newId) {
        console.log('ids are the same');
    } else {
        console.log('ids are not the same');
    }
};

useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket(url);

    socket.addEventListener('open', () => {
        console.log('socket connection opened');
    });

    socket.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(msg.data);

        if (data.eventType === 'one') {
            functionOne(data.id);
        }

        if (data.eventType === 'two') {
            functionTwo(data.id);
        }
    }) 

    socket.addEventListener('close', () => {
        console.log('socket connection closed');
    });
}, []);
```

I have a `useState`-hook for an ID. And I have two events which are sent from the server over websockets to the app: event "one" and event "two".

In event "one": I send a unique ID to the app, and I store this ID in the useState-id-hook. This works, because when I do a console.log in a useEffect-function to see if the state changes, it works.

After 1 minute, I receive another socket message with event type = "two" and the exact same ID I received a minute before. I want to compare this "new" ID with the previous received ID.

The problem is: when running functionTwo(), it seems that the useState-hook still is stuck in the original state, eg. "null". It does get updated by this update is not reflected in functionTwo(), where the value of "id" is still "null".

Wrapping functionTwo() in a useCallback(functionTwo, [id]) didn't work.

What is wrong with my code?

**Edit:**

Thank you to T.J. Crowder, the suggestion for using redux worked in my case.

I created a custom hook which mimicks a useState hook, but stores the values in redux. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

This is the classic function-closes-over-stale-state problem, *slightly* obscured by making it indirect through `functionTwo`.

The issue is that your `useEffect` callback *closes over* the version of `functionTwo` from the first render, which in turn *closes over* the value of `id` from the first render. Later versions of `id` and `functionTwo` aren't used, because your dependency array for the `useEffect` is empty. (A decent lint plugin would warn you about this.)

There are a couple of ways to solve it:

1. Add `functionTwo` as a dependency on the `useEffect`, and be sure to add appropriate cleanup code (in a cleanup function you return from your `useEffect` callback) so you don't re-subscribe to the socket (and so you unsubscribe when dismounting).

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
       function openHandler() {
           console.log("socket connection opened");
       }
       function messageHandler(msg) {
           const data = JSON.parse(msg.data);

           if (data.eventType === "one") {
               functionOne(data.id);
           }

           if (data.eventType === "two") {
               functionTwo(data.id);
           }
       }
       function closeHandler() {
           console.log("socket connection closed");
       }

       const socket = new WebSocket(url);
       socket.addEventListener("open", openHandler);
       socket.addEventListener("message", messageHandler);
       socket.addEventListener("close", closeHandler);
       return () => {
           // NOTE: It's important to use the *same functions* when removing the handlers,
           // which is why I've separated them out from the `addEventListener` calls
           socket.removeEventListener("open", openHandler);
           socket.removeEventListener("message", messageHandler);
           socket.removeEventListener("close", closeHandler);
       };
   }, [functionTwo]);
   ```

   Note that this means the effect runs on *every render*. You could make it happen less often by adding back the `useCallback` you mentioned for `functionTwo` so `functionTwo` is stable for any given `id` value, so (in turn) the effect only happens when `id` changes.
2. Add a `ref` that has the up-to-date version of `id`, and use that `ref` in `functionTwo` instead of directly using `id`.

   ```
   const [id, setId] = useState(null);
   const idRef = useRef(null);
   idRef.current = id;

   // ...

   const functionTwo = (newId) => {
       if (idRef.current === newId) {
           console.log("ids are the same");
       } else {
           console.log("ids are not the same");
       }
   };
   ```

   That way, it doesn't matter that `functionTwo` is possibly-stale.
3. Use Redux or similar instead of `useState`. (An example is beyond the scope of this answer.)

Comment: Good answer, though I'll cast my vote that option 2 makes more sense in this case since you really don't want to be reconnecting to the websocket and/or re-adding a message listener every time

Comment: @lucasvw - Yeah, it does seem like that wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: I'm going to try the option with redux, I'm already using that in my app. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've updated my question. Your suggestion to use redux worked. Thank you, you saved me a couple hours into the night!

Comment: @SamLeurs - Glad that helped! Your question edit would be better as a comment or even an answer. On SO, we don't edit solutions *into* questions. Happy coding!